# Simple mail sender

Tags: android, email, smtp, gmail

Earlier I was using an intent to complete this operation:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"xxxxxxx@gmail.com"});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            try{
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Feedback to TFC"));
            }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

But then again the intent results in a form with the address, subject and the message. For now I only want the message part. I did have a look at [this blog](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/) . Is it necessary to give the username and password ?? Is there no simple `mailto:` function in `android` as we see in `html` so that the message is just sent without me having to use the all the complicated functions ?

Comment: Can you specifically state your requirement..?

Comment: @ArunCThomas How can I without using Intents send email. And even in the process of sending the email ... is there no easy mailto: like function found in html because when I read the blog mentioned earlier, the process seemed quite complicated. I just want to create a function that sends a simple message.

Comment: The most simple way in android to send email is via intent, other wise you need to implement one mailing service, it is quite complicated

Comment: oh well that's not nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/1051147 which explains how to *Send e-mail in Android using the JavaMail API using Gmail authentication*

note that you will need some additional jar for getting it done.  As i explained the simplest method is to use  intent.

Comment: the lines Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this) is giving me a problem in the GmailSender class. Could you please resolve ? The error being NoClassDefFoundError.